# What formula can make a non-linear transformation into a matrix transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**What formula can make a non-linear transformation into a matrix transformation?**

This problem showed up on an exam, 
I was really shocked that I never heard one of them...

From my understanding, this question asks me is there any formula which can make $T(x) = x^2$, a non-linear transformation into a matrix transformation ?
What am I supposed to answer to this question?

Please save me from full of confusion, thank you!

Comment: The question is severely ill-posed. Are you sure you wrote it in its entirety?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Sorry but yes I am....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the question is rather poor. There is no linear transformation $S$ such that $S(x) = x^2$, so there is no linear transformation that agrees with $T$ everywhere.

On the other hand, there is a "natural" way to obtain a linear transformation $S$ from $T(x) = x^2$, and that would be to take the derivative. The derivative $S(x) = T'(x) = 2x$ is the linear map which scales vectors by $2x$.

More generally, given a "non-linear" (but still differentiable) map $T\colon\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$, written in the standard bases as
$$
T(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \big(T_1(x_1,\dots,x_n),\dots,T_m(x_1,\dots,x_n)\big),
$$ 
the derivative $DT_p$ at any point $p = (p_1,\dots,p_n)$ is a linear map $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$. Moreover, in the standard bases, $DT_p$ can be identified with the $m\times n$ Jacobian matrix of partial derivatives:
$$
DT_p =
\begin{pmatrix}
{\partial T_1 \over \partial x_1}(p) & {\partial T_1 \over \partial x_2}(p) & \dots & {\partial T_1 \over \partial x_n}(p) \\
{\partial T_2 \over \partial x_1}(p) & {\partial T_2 \over \partial x_2}(p) & \dots & {\partial T_2 \over \partial x_n}(p) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
{\partial T_m \over \partial x_1}(p) & {\partial T_m \over \partial x_2}(p) & \dots & {\partial T_m \over \partial x_n}(p)
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
The upshot is that as long as we look at points $q = (q_1,\dots,q_n)$ that are "very small," then the affine transformation $q\mapsto T(p) + DT_p(q)$ closely approximates the (in general nonlinear) map $q\mapsto T(p+q)$.

So, for the example $T\colon \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined by $T(x) = x^2$, we get a linear map at every point $p$ defined as $DT_p$, which we typically just write as $T'(p)$, which is really just a $1\times 1$ matrix $T'(p) = (2p)$. As a linear map acting on $1\times 1$ column vectors $(q)$, we have
$$
DT_p(q) = T'(p)(q) = (2p)(q) = (2pq).
$$
Hence the end result is that "vectors" $(q)$ are mapped linearly to $(2pq)$ by the derivative, and if we identify $1\times 1$ matrices with numbers,
\begin{align*}
T(p+q) = (p+q)^2 &= p^2 + 2pq + q^2 \\
&\approx p^2 + 2pq \qquad\qquad\text{(small numbers like $q$ are "negligible" if we square them)}\\
&= T(p) + 2pq \\
&= T(p) + T'(p)q,
\end{align*}
so long as $q$ is sufficiently small. You may recognize that $T(p) + T'(p)q$ is really the first-order Taylor polynomial of $T$ at $p$ (i.e. [the best affine approximation near $p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784262/how-is-the-derivative-truly-literally-the-best-linear-approximation-near-a-po/1784303)).

Answer (score 0):

I would say "You could multiply it by zero." :)

Comment: Good answer! Extreme conditions require extreme responses. :-)

Comment: lol, you made my day