# If there is a linear function $g$ which is at least as good of an approximation as any other linear $h$, then $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

This question is related to one in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784262/how-is-the-derivative-truly-literally-the-best-linear-approximation-near-a-po?noredirect=1&lq=1) where the author asks what is the intuition behind saying that derivative is the best linear approximation. One of the answers by user "Milo Brandt" is that we have two theorems, one of which is: $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ if and only if there is a linear function $g$ which is at least as good of an approximation as any other linear $h$.

I am struggling to prove one part of this theorem. First, I think that $g$ and $h$ are supposed to be affine and not linear in a sense that $g(x) = A + B(x-x_0)$ and $h(x) = C + D(x-x_0)$ where $A,C \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $B,D : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ are linear functions.

Assume that there is such function $g$ which is at least as good as an approximation as any other $h$. By definition, this means that there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ that have $|x - x_0 | < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - g(x)| \leq |h(x) - f(x)|$.

I would like to show that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$, in other words, that there exists a linear function $\lambda : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that:

$$ \lim \limits_{x \to x_0} \frac{|f(x) - f(x_0) - \lambda(x-x_0)|}{|x-x_0|} = 0 $$

This translates to be able to find such $\lambda$ so that for each $\varepsilon > 0$ we can find $\delta > 0$ such that when $|x - x_0| < \delta$, we have $|f(x) - f(x_0) - \lambda(x-x_0)| < \varepsilon |x-x_0|$.

I think intuitively, I would like to show that $\lambda = B$ is correct choice. From $g$ being as good as approximation as any $h$, I have the following: there is $\delta > 0 $ so that for all $|x - x_0| < \delta$ I have $|f(x) - g(x)| \leq |C - f(x) + D(x-x_0)|$. Now, I can use triangle inequality and also result that I have already proven which is that any linear function $D$ is bounded in the following way: $|D(x-x_0)| < M|x-x_0|$.

In this case, I can show that I can always find $\delta > 0$ such that for all $|x-x_0| <\delta$ I have
$|f(x) - g(x) | \leq |C-f(x)+D(x-x_0)| \leq |C - f(x)| + |D(x-x_0)| < |C - f(x)| + M|x-x_0|$. As $h$ is arbitrary, I could choose $M = \varepsilon$ as I also know that $M = \sqrt{mn}$ $ \mathrm{max}_{ij}|D_{ij}|$. But then I would only get that $|f(x) - g(x)| < |C - f(x)| + \varepsilon |x-x_0|$.

How to get rid of the second term? Should I use continuity? Do I somehow use that $g$ is linear now? Any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: No, $C-f(x)$ would not be $o(\lvert x-x_0\rvert)$, so your bound is useless without needing to control $M$.

Comment: @user10354138 yes, it seems like that, thanks for confirming. Do you have some another bound in mind?

Comment: Also, you are not formulating "at least as good ... as any other $h$" correctly, because I can always pick $x_1\in B(x_0,r)$ and make sure $h(x_1)=f(x_1)$, which defeats your "for all $x$ ... $\lvert f(x)-g(x)\rvert\leq\lvert f(x)-h(x)\rvert$ unless the function $f(x)-g(x)=0$  for all $x$, i.e., $f$ is affine linear, not something we want.

Comment: @user10354138 I think the intended meaning is that for any linear $h$ there is a neighborhood $U_h$ of $x_0$ where the inequality holds.

Comment: @DanielsKrimans could you please post the other direction to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4041119/best-linear-approximation-in-a-neighborhood-property-for-frechet-derivative

Answer (score 4):

I'll be following a different path to the result. To simplify, I'll assume $x_0=0$ and $f(0)=0.$ Also I'll assume $m=1.$ So $f$ is real valued in some neighborhood of $0$ in $\mathbb R^n.$

Assume there exists a linear function $g:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ that is a best linear approximation to $f.$ That means that for any linear $h:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ there exists a neighborhood $U_h$ of $0$ such that

$$|f(x)-g(x)|\le |f(x)-h(x)| \text{ for all } x\in U_h.$$

We want to show $Df(0)=g.$ I.e.,

$$\tag 1 \frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{|x|}\to 0$$

as $x\to 0$ through nonzero vectors.

Suppose $(1)$ fails. Then there is $\epsilon>0$ and a sequence $x_k\to 0$ such that

$$ |f(x_k)-g(x_k)|\ge \epsilon|x_k|$$

for all $k.$ It follows that for each $k,$ either i) $f(x_k)-g(x_k)\ge \epsilon|x_k|$ or ii) $f(x_k)-g(x_k)\le -\epsilon|x_k|.$ At least one of those holds for infinitely many $k;$ let's assume it's i). Instead of subsequence notation, I'll assume WLOG i) holds for all $k.$

Write $x_k=r_ku_k,$ where $r_k=|x_k|$ and $u_k= x_k/|x_k|.$ The $u_k$ are unit vectors, and since the unit sphere $S$ is compact, there exists a subsequence of $u_k$ that converges to some $u_0\in S.$ I'll continue to abuse notation and assum $u_k$ is this subsequence.

Define $L(tu_0) = t(\epsilon/2),t\in \mathbb R.$ Then extend $L$ to be linear on $\mathbb R^n$ in any way you like. Then $g+L$ is linear on $\mathbb R^n.$

Claim: There exists $K$ such that

$$0<f(x_k)-(g(x_k)+L(x_k))< f(x_k)-g(x_k)$$

for $k>K.$

If we prove the claim, we have a contradiction, since then in every neighborhood of $0$ there exist points where $|f-(g+L)|< |f-g|,$ violating the best approximation property of $g.$

Proof of claim: We start with

$$f(x_k)-(g(x_k)+L(x_k)) = f(x_k)-g(x_k)-L(x_k).$$

Now observe

$$ -L(x_k) =-r_kL(u_k)+r_kL(u_0)-r_kL(u_0)$$ $$= r_k(L(u_0)-L(u_k))-r_k\epsilon/2 .$$

Now $L(u_0)-L(u_k)\to 0$ as $k\to \infty.$ So there exists $K$ such that $|L(u_0)-L(u_k)|<\epsilon/4$ for $k\ge K.$ It follows that for such $k,$

$$-3r_k\epsilon/4 < -L(x_k) < -r_k\epsilon/4.$$

Since $f(x_k)-g(x_k)\ge \epsilon r_k,$ the claim is proved.

Answer (score 3):

I got a bit lost in the notation in your attempt - you can get away with using a lot fewer variables than you're doing. Just for clarity, I'll prove the following, where I've also translated everything to $0$:

> Suppose that $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R^m$ is a function and $g:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R^m$ is an affine function with the property that for every other affine $h:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R^m$ there exists some $\delta$ such that if $|x|<\delta$ then $$|f(x)-g(x)|\leq |f(x)-h(x)|.$$
> Then,
> $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{|x|}=0.$$

And, since we're going to unravel all of the notation anyways, we may as well write the conclusion as its definition:

> For every $\varepsilon > 0 $ there exists some $\delta$ such that if $|x|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-g(x)| \leq \varepsilon |x|$.

Let's prove the theorem by contrapositive - suppose there were some $\varepsilon > 0$ and some sequence of $x_n$ approaching $x$ such that $|f(x_i)-g(x_i)| > \varepsilon|x_i|$. We will show that $g$ is not the best linear approximation of $f$.

such that for all $\delta > 0$ there would exist some $|x|<\delta$ such that $|f(x_i)-g(x_i)| > \varepsilon |x_i|$. We want to show that $g$ is not the best linear approximation.

Let $D$ be the set of linear transformations (not affine transformations) of operator norm exactly $\varepsilon$. This is a compact set. For each $x_i$, choose some $M_i\in D$ such that $|f(x_i)-g(x_i)-M_i(x_i)| = |f(x_i)-g(x_i)| - \varepsilon |x_i|$ - any matrix which sends $x_i$ to something parallel and cancelling with to the error vector $f(x_i)-g(x_i)$ suffices. Note that if $\|M-M_i\| < \varepsilon$ in the operator norm, then $|f(x_i)-g(x_i)-M(x_i)| < |f(x_i)-g(x_i)|$.

Let $M$ be any limit point of the sequence $M_i$, noting that such an $M$ exists by compactness of $D$. Then, we observe that there must be infinitely many $x_i$ such that $|f(x_i)-g(x_i)-M(x_i)| < |f(x_i)-g(x_i)|$ since $M$ is an limit of some subsequence. Note that $M\neq 0$, thus $g$ is not a better affine transformation than $g+M$ - as desired. Thus, if $\frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{|x|}$ fails to converge to $0$, $g$ is not the best affine approximation of $f$.

---

However: I don't think there are many functions of two variables that have a best affine approximation. The trouble is that if you had some continuous function $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$ and a linear function $g:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$ and some line $\ell$ through the origin on which $g$ did not exactly equal $f$ on an open set around the origin, then any other linear function $h:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow\mathbb R$ which agreed with $g$ on $\ell$ but differed elsewhere would, in any ball around the origin, have some point where $h$ approximates $f$ better than $g$, since if some point on $\ell$ fails to agree exactly with $g$, by moving slightly to some direction, we can make $h$ either slightly greater or less than $g$, and thus bring it closer to the value of $f$. I would suspect that this means that a continuous function with a best linear approximation is in fact linear itself. This issue doesn't come up in one dimension where this geometric problem doesn't arise.

Comment: do I understand correctly that by your remark in the end you wanted to say that for multivariable functions, it is not true that if it is differentiable then there exists the best linear approximation?

Comment: @DanielsKrimans Indeed - I think the situation is quite bad in that regard. For instance, one would imagine that $x^2+y^2$ has $0$ as the best linear approximation near $(x,y)=(0,0)$ except that the function $x$ agrees exactly with $x^2+y^2$ on a curve through the origin and $0$ does not - hence $0$ is not a better linear approximation than $x$. The whole thing falls apart in 2D, apparently - it only works in 1D because two linear functions in 1D have to, at every point, be different by some uniform multiple of $|x|$.

Comment: thanks for help! I dont know if I should ask a new question, but I didn't understand what you mean by ''$x$ agrees exactly with $x^2+y^2$ on a curve through origin and $0$ does not''. These functions agree on two points, say, $0$ and $a$, right? I agree that at point $a$, $x$ is closer to function than $0$, but it still could be that there is neighbourhood with radius smaller than $a$ so that $0$ is better of approximation?

Comment: @DanielsKrimans They agree on the set of solutions to $x = \frac{1-\sqrt{1+4y^2}}2$ which passes through the origin - so there's no ball around the origin at which such a solution is avoided.

Comment: thanks - this is really helpful! Do you know of any way to make derivative be the "best" linear approximation by changing the definition of "best" approximation?

Comment: @DanielsKrimans I'm not sure - it seems hard to do without appealing to a sense of a sublinear error term, but then you're just back at the usual definition of derivative from limits.

Comment: @DanielsKrimans If you say $g$ is a better approx. of $f$ near $a$ than $h$ iff $a$ is not an interior point of the set $|f-h|\leq|f-g|$, then it is fairly easy to prove that the shifted differential application is always the best affine approximation. I'm trying to prove the converse, without success for now, maybe you can give it a try as well :)