# Is deriviation is the only way to get a good liner approximation at a point $p$? How does one compare two different linear approximations?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Take $f(x) = x ^ 2$ and $p = 3$ for a simplicity sake. Then $f'(x)$ allows to define a linear approximation of the $f(p)$ in the following way: $l(x) = f'(p)(x - p) + f(p)$. Often enough it is stated that $l(x)$ is *the* best linear approximation one could possible find, however I've never seen how one compares some linear approximation to another to be able to deduce which is better?

For example, take $l(x) = 3x$ instead. It does approximate $f(x)$ at the $p$ perfectly: $f(p) = 3 ^ 2 = 9 = l(p) = 3 \times 3$, and also it's error function $e(x) = f(p) - l(x)$ does approach $0$ given that $x$ approaches $p$ either way.

So both of them yield *the same* perfect approximation at the point $p$, both offer arbitrary little errors for some $(p - \delta, p + \delta), \delta > 0$. How do I convince myself then that one is indeed better then the other?

Comment: [Perhaps the discussion here will be useful.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784262/how-is-the-derivative-truly-literally-the-best-linear-approximation-near-a-po)

Comment: So in the title "deriviation" means the derivative?

Comment: By "deriviation" I mean "process of computing derivative".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative $f^\prime$ of a function $f$ satisfies the requirement that
$$f(x+h) - f(x) = f^\prime(x)h + o(|h|)$$
where $o$ is a function which satisfies $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{o(|h|}{|h|} = 0.$

Geometrically this means that the tangent to the graph of $f$ at $x$ has slope $f^\prime(x)$.-

I suggest you convince yourself of the fact that your function $l(x)$ does not have this property with respect to $f(x) = x^2$ in $x=3$. The statement you wrote down about $e$ approaching $0$ in $x$ (it only works for $x=3$, btw) is just the statement that both functions $f$ and $l$ are continuous in $x=3$ and evaluate to the same value (their graphs intersect, but graph of the linear function $l$ is not tangent to the one of $f$ in that point). For an answer to your question you should vist  [the question for which PrincessEev provided a link in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1784262/how-is-the-derivative-truly-literally-the-best-linear-approximation-near-a-po)

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider a function $f$ which is continuous at $p$ and a linear function $l(x) = ax +b$. When should we regard $l$ as a linear approximation of $f$ at $p$?

Let us introduce the *approximation error function*
$$\varepsilon(x) = f(x) - l(x)  \tag{1} $$
which is continuous at $p$. With some justification we may call $l$ a linear approximation of $f$ at $p$ if $\varepsilon(p) = 0$. That is, we require $l(p) = f(p)$ which results in
$$l(p) = a(x-p) + f(p) . \tag{2}$$
There are infinitely many linear function of this form, but does one of them deserve to be called the **best** linear approximation? This requires to **define** what it means to be an optimal linear approximation. A reasonable approach is to look at the *relative approximation error*
$$\rho(h) = \frac{\varepsilon(p+h)}{h} \tag{3}$$
which is defined for $h \ne 0$. The best what can happen is that
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \rho(h) = 0 . \tag{4}$$

This means
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(p+h) - l(p+h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(p+h) - f(p) - ah}{h} = 0 .\tag{5} $$
In other words, $(4)$ is satisfied if and only if $a$ has the property
$$a = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(p+h) - f(p)}{h} .\tag{6} $$
This means that $f$ is differentiable at $p$. Precisely in this case $f$ has a linear approximation at $p$ such that the relative approximation error $\rho(h)$ goes to $0$ when $h$ goes to $0$. As we have seen there is only one such linear approximation; it is
$$l(x) = f'(p)(x-p) + f(p) . \tag{7}$$